# How to convert from HTML JS CSS image slideshow into Joomla Module

Tags: html, image, joomla, slider

Please check the Url: http://www.bp.com, There is a image slide, I need to this slide to convert Joomla Module. For this, I have sort the code from site and I have added HTMl part to Joomla custom Module area. And then I have added css and js file into template index.php file. Design looks fine, but it's slide part does not work at all.

Please help me how can I solve it or any idea to build such image slide by using Jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    nvs.link.init();
    // Initialise branding
    nvs.utils.branding.init();        
});
```

I have tried and my url is [here](http://onlinetotalsolutions.com/joomla30)

It will be really appreciated.

Comment: show what you have so far

Comment: Hi here is progress: http://onlinetotalsolutions.com/joomla30/

Comment: Update your question with the code you have so far

Comment: We can't help unless you show your code. Reason for it not working could be hundreds of different thing, but we can't help unless we have something to look at. If you're extremely new to this, you might want to look at a slideshow extension on the Joomla Extensions Directory

Answer (score 0):

Joomla loads jquery in **noConflict** mode.

You have to change your code to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    nvs.link.init();
    // Initialise branding
    nvs.utils.branding.init();        
});
```

Reference: [Javascript Frameworks](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks) - [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)